# How can I make a List<string> into a string[] using LINQ?

Tags: c#

I have this code that returns a List

```
   var addRoles = newRoles
      .Where(x => oldRoles
      .All(y => y != x))
      .ToList();
```

I am using this in a method however the method requires a string array:

```
string[]
```

How can I make the addRoles variable into a string array?

Comment: `addRoles.ToArray()`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`ToArray()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x303t819%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
var addRoles = newRoles
      .Where(x => oldRoles
      .All(y => y != x))
      .ToArray();
```